# erro java, cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arrays

well, i'm new in this and i dont know how i can make this program works, i need Write a program that calculates and returns the sum of the components of a vector squared

and i got this error:

```
import java.util.*;
public class cuadrado
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Scanner teclado= new Scanner (System.in);
        int n=0,i=0,y=0;       

        System.out.println("ingrese el valor de el vector");

        n=teclado.nextInt();

        int[ ]suma=new int[n];

        for(i=0;i<suma.lenght;i=i+1);
        {
            System.out.println("ingrese el valor de un numero");
            suma[i]=teclado.nextInt();
            y+=suma[i];
            System.out.println(""+y);         


        }


    }
}
```

cannot find symbol in the line 16

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;` from the end of line `for(i=0;i<suma.lenght;i=i+1);`

EDIT

Also, what @ankur-singhal said, `suma.length` instead of `suma.lenght` (nice catch).

Comment: thank you so much guy, i worked on this for about two hours, and now i fell like a stupid :)

Answer (score 1):

change `suma.lenght` to `suma.length`, `length` is the function to find length of array

Answer (score 1):

By adding the semicolon at the end of your for loop, you're looping on a blank statement before you even reach your code block. Then, when you reach your i inside the code block, it is undefined, because you are now out of the context of the for loop.